# how to design correct XML and retrieve values on the basis of request name?

Tags: java, xml

I want to create singleton class that read request name values from the XML configuration file only one time and store values into an memory, but i am confused how to design my XML configuration file which full fill my requirement.

my designed XML file:

```
       <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <config>
               <Request name="validateEmailRequest">
                   <requestqueue>emailrequest</requestqueue>
                   <responsequeue>emailresponse</responsequeue>
               </Request>

             <Request name="cleanEmail">
                   <requestqueue>cleanrequest</requestqueue>
                   <responsequeue>cleanresponse</responsequeue>
             </Request>

       </config>
```

please help me to design an XML and also how to store and retrieve respected values.

Thanks

Comment: I'm presuming you are asking for the code to read and write the XML? Perhaps you should clarify what it is you need as there are a large number of APIs and techniques that could be used to access this XML.

Answer (score 0):

For configuring Java applications, it is really recommended to use the build-in Properties functionality. Properties are (singleton) key/value-pairs. They are however stored in a plain-text format rather than XML.
More information can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

In order to structure the properties, the naming convention is to use dotted names. 
Your properties-file, could thus look like this:

```
validateEmailRequest.requestQueue = emailrequest
validateEmailRequest.responsQueue = emailresponse
cleanEmail.requestQueue = cleanrequest
cleanEmail.responseQueue = cleanresponse
```

The above link also provides information about reading and writing the properties.